# D3.js Arrow-like path around text

Tags: d3.js

I want to reproduce this beautiful arrow-like [tooltip](http://www.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2013/11/30/football-conferences/) and since the source code is not accessible i am asking myself: 
how to make a "background" path for the tooltip body which fits the overlaying text block.

Do i have to create the text element and then calculate the width via `getBoundingClientRect()` and insert the width it into a custom path ?

Edit: just found the solution in a non minified js of bostock.

```
var tooltipRect = tooltipContent.node().getBoundingClientRect(),
    tooltipWidth = tooltipRect.width,
    tooltipHeight = tooltipRect.height;

tooltipPath
    .attr("width", tooltipWidth)
    .attr("height", tooltipHeight + 6)
  .select("path")
    .attr("d", "M0,0"
        + "H" + tooltipWidth
        + "v" + tooltipHeight
        + "H" + (tooltipWidth / 2 + 6)
        + "l-6,6"
        + "l-6,-6"
        + "H0"
        + "z");

tooltipOverlay
    .style("left", (d.x + margin.left - tooltipWidth / 2) + "px")
    .style("top", (d.y + margin.top - tooltipHeight - 6) + "px");
```

Comment: That sounds like the way to go if you're using SVG to do it.

Comment: @chrispie - can you tell us where is the non minified code?

Comment: @VividD - i found it [here](http://www.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2013/09/07/director-star-chart/)